# Wordpress REST API - Permission Callbacks

Tags: permissions, authentication, rest-api, callbacks

I'm currently building a small REST API with the WP-REST v2 plugin. Everything is working perfectly fine, however, in the documentation there are permission callbacks, which restrict access to certain user groups (exactly what I'm trying to do). The syntax provided is as follows:

```
'permission_callback' => function () {
    return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
}
```

The issue I'm having is that at the point of execution the current user is empty, despite being logged in and authenticated as an administrative account (session tokens exist in the cookies before, during and after the request). I figured that it may be because the route endpoint returns a page with nothing but the response text, so I tried calling the API from the index.php and `wp_get_current_user();`returns an empty user object and therefore `current_user_can('condition')` will never succeed.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10):

The issue was because I wasn't generating and sending a `nonce` value with the request. In order to generate a `nonce` value. Localize the value of a `wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')` function call.

```
wp_localize_script('application', 'api', array(
    'root' => esc_url_raw(rest_url()),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')
));
```

This will then be accessible to the `window` object of the browser which can be accessed via Javascript, this `nonce` should then be passed as the value of the request header `X-WP-Nonce` when executing XHR / HTTP Requests. An example of which is as follows:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}

request.open('GET', api.root + 'mynamespace/posts');

// You must set headers after the request has been opened and before itself.
request.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce`, api.nonce);

request.send(); // will fire the event listener above when fulfilled.
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: I am curious about where you would add this code exactly? functions.php or in a plugin? I am struggling with a similar issue..

Comment: Hi @anniec, the `wp_localize_script` function is called in functions.php and simply adds a property to the `window` object in the browser which can be accessed via Javascript, in the example above the `wp_localize_script` call adds a property to the window object called `api` when the script `application` is enqueued. The third parameter then sets the value of `window.api` so in the above example, `window.api.root` would return the escaped rest api url and `window.api.nonce` would return the rest api nonce. This nonce must be sent as a request header to check the current user's permissions.